# Cross-validating a CART model

Tags: r, cross-validation, rpart

In an assignment, we are asked to perform a cross-validation on a CART model. I have tried using the `cvFit` function from `cvTools` but got a strange error message. Here's a minimal example:

```
library(rpart)
library(cvTools)
data(iris)
cvFit(rpart(formula=Species~., data=iris))
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Error in nobs(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

And the `traceback()`:

```
5: nobs(y)
4: cvFit.call(call, data = data, x = x, y = y, cost = cost, K = K, 
       R = R, foldType = foldType, folds = folds, names = names, 
       predictArgs = predictArgs, costArgs = costArgs, envir = envir, 
       seed = seed)
3: cvFit(call, data = data, x = x, y = y, cost = cost, K = K, R = R, 
       foldType = foldType, folds = folds, names = names, predictArgs = predictArgs, 
       costArgs = costArgs, envir = envir, seed = seed)
2: cvFit.default(rpart(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris))
1: cvFit(rpart(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris))
```

It looks that `y` is mandatory for `cvFit.default`. But:

```
> cvFit(rpart(formula=Species~., data=iris), y=iris$Species)
Error in cvFit.call(call, data = data, x = x, y = y, cost = cost, K = K,  : 
  'x' must have 0 observations
```

What am I doing wrong? Which package would allow me to do a cross-validation with a CART tree without having to code it myself? (I am sooo lazy...)

Comment: If you dig into the documentation for **cvTools** it appears that most of those tools were built with continuous response variables in mind, rather than discrete. You could probably get it to work, but it looks like you'd have to supply your own function to `cost` to calculate the classification error.

Comment: @joran: Exactly -- thank you! See [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16724706/946850).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The caret package makes cross validation a snap:

```
> library(caret)
> data(iris)
> tc <- trainControl("cv",10)
> rpart.grid <- expand.grid(.cp=0.2)
> 
> (train.rpart <- train(Species ~., data=iris, method="rpart",trControl=tc,tuneGrid=rpart.grid))
150 samples
  4 predictors
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validation (10 fold) 

Summary of sample sizes: 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy  Kappa  Accuracy SD  Kappa SD
  0.94      0.91   0.0798       0.12    

Tuning parameter 'cp' was held constant at a value of 0.2
```

Comment: Wow. Just look at the list of supported methods in `train`. That's what I call comprehensive... There's a lot of "magic" happening here. Is it possible to access only the cross validation routine, without actually optimizing the model parameters?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can define your own grid of parameters. If you don't want to test multiple models then  they could just be set to static values. I'll illustrate this by editing my above example.

Comment: What is caret? I don't see that being used in your answer.

Comment: A library that I forgot to include in the code, made an edit so it should be all set now.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I was able to get it to work. As Joran noted, the `cost` parameter needs to be adapted. In my case I am using 0/1 loss, which means that I use a simple function that evaluates `!=` instead of `-` between `y` and `yHat`. Also, `predictArgs` must include `c(type='class')`, otherwise the `predict` call used internally will return a vector of probabilities instead of the most probable classification. To sum up:

```
library(rpart)
library(cvTools)
data(iris)
cvFit(rpart, formula=Species~., data=iris,
      cost=function(y, yHat) (y != yHat) + 0, predictArgs=c(type='class'))
```

(This uses another variant of `cvFit`. Additional args to `rpart` can be passed by setting the `args=` parameter.)